# jQuery Validator rule applying to wrong element

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-validate

After unsuccessfully trying to apply a required rule to a dropdown (yes, I did have an option with an empty value), I created a custom rule to apply to my dropdown. As I discovered by adding an alert, jQuery Validator is not looking at the `<select>` tag I'm referencing, `selectFruitResult`. Instead, it's looking at the one above it: `selectTypeResult`. I assume that simply using the built-in required rule was also looking at the wrong element. Why? What am I doing wrong here?

HTML:

```
    <form id="fruitResultForm">
        <div class="form-group">
              <label for="selectTypeResult">Select a fruit by Type:</label>
              <select class="form-control" id="selectTypeResult" style="width: 300px;">
                <option>APPLES</option>
                <option>ORANGES</option>
                <option>CHERRIES</option>
                <option>GRAPES</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" id="selectFruitDiv">
              <select class="form-control" id="selectFruitResult" style="width: 300px;"></select>
            </div>
          </div>
</form>
```

JavaScript (note that the validator is initialized and `form.validate()` is called in another file):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#selectTypeResult").on("change", function(e){
    var optionSelected = $('#selectTypeResult').find('option:selected');
    var groupType = optionSelected.val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/getfruit.json,
        type: "GET",
        success: function (data) {
            // Clear options in selectFruit dropdown.
            $("#selectFruitResult").empty();

            // Populate new options in selectFruit dropdown.
            if (data.fruit.length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.fruit.length; i++) {
                    $("#selectFruitResult").append("<option value='" + data.fruit[i].categoryId + "'>" + data.fruit[i].name + "</option>");
                }
            } else {
                $("#selectFruitResult").append('<option value="None">No existing fruits of this type</option>');
                jQuery.validator.addMethod("emptyFruit", function(value, element) {
                    alert(value);
                    return value != "None";
                }, 'Please select an existing fruit');
                $("#selectFruitResult").rules('add', 'emptyFruit');
            }

        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong here?

Neither of your `select` elements contains a `name` attribute. The jQuery Validate plugin mandates that all elements considered for validation contain a unique `name` attribute.  It's just how the plugin keeps track of everything.  There is no workaround for this.

```
<select class="form-control" name="selectFruitResult" id="selectFruitResult" style="width: 300px;">
```

Now as long as the first `option` contains `value=''`, you won't need to use a custom rule, and the built-in  `required` will function as expected.